# JSF navigation not working in RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have what I thought was simple JSF navigation setup but when I hit the `h:commandButton` the page reloads, not the page I want to load.  The faces-config snippet is here:

```
    <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/index.jsf</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>hello</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/next.jsf</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

the index.xhtml file contains this:

```
<f:view>
    <a4j:region id="topRegion">
        <rich:page pageTitle="myapp" markupType="xhtml" id="top">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:form>
    <rich:toolBar height="45" itemSeparator="disc">
        <rich:toolBarGroup location="left">
            <h:form name="selectForm">
                <h:panelGrid columns="5" style="padding: 2px;">
                    <h:outputText style="text-align: center" value="Node Select " />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="nodes" value="#{MyBacking.chosenNode}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{MyBacking.nodes}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:commandButton value="Retrieve" styleClass="ctrlBtn"
                        id="retrieveBtn" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"
                        action="hello"
                        image="/img/btnRetrieve26.png" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </rich:toolBarGroup>
    </rich:toolBar>
</h:form>
```

It's as simple as that.  Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

As far as I'm aware, the from-outcome of hello should be used by the `h:commandbutton` and load next.xhtml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your files are .xhtml not .jsf

have you tried:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>hello</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/next.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Good grief.  You're right.  My confusion came in from the web descriptor where I've been used to specifying a url-pattern of *.jsf and a DEFAULT_SUFFIX of .xhtml. Cheers!